# Blender renders everything pitch black

Tags: light

I am trying to render out an image of a character I made, but when I render it, it acts like there is no light of any sort in the scene, I have tried the different lamps, turning on and off ambient occlusion, and emission planes, but none have worked. edit (It's not blank, the model is just black the background is still the right color.) [image: Settings]

[image: This Is It Final Render]

[image]

Comment: Do you screenshots or a file we can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I believe I found the problem.

[image]